# C# MSAGL- display styles

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, msagl

[image]

This is a winform application in C# with MSAGL.
I'm trying to change the color of the gray zone to white,and change the font style of the Node, what should I do to set them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `OutsideAreaBrush` property of the viewer to desired brush in load event of your form, for example:

```
this.gViewer.OutsideAreaBrush = Brushes.White;
```